# Crystal Report does not load

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

My Crystal Report does not load.

This is my code:

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared

Public Class bincard
    Private Sub bincard_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument

        cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "bincard1.rpt")

        Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
        Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
        Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
        Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue

        crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = TextBox1.Text
        crParameterFieldDefinitions =
            cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
        crParameterFieldDefinition =
            crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("itemid")
        crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues

        crParameterValues.Clear()
        crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
        crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed:

```
cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "bincard1.rpt")
```

To:

```
cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath & "bincard1.rpt")
```

Then report design set to copy output directory=copy if newer and compile to content.

Answer (score 0):

From:

```
cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "bincard1.rpt")
```

To:

```
cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\bincard1.rpt")
```

Answer (score -1):

Your path in `cryRpt.Load()` is wrong. As it stands it will look something like this:

> C:\Program Files\Application Namebincard1.rpt

Notice how there is no [backslash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash) between `"Application Name"` and `"bincard1.rpt"`. This would make the path invalid. That is because you are using `+` to concatenate paths which will cause some issues.

Instead consider using [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) to join `Application.StartupPath` and `"bincard1.rpt"` together:

```
cryRpt.Load(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "bincard1.rpt"))
```

This will give you a path similar to:

> C:\Program Files\Application Name\bincard1.rpt